# GeoExt2 FormPanel Wfs Filtering

Tags: javascript, extjs, openlayers, geoext

I'm developing a web project using Extjs, GeoExt2, Openlayers etc.
I'm using  `FormPanel` from GeoExt2 to make wfs requests by filter.
[GeoExt Api Link](http://geoext.github.io/geoext2/docs-w-ext/#!/api/GeoExt.form.action.Search)

```
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
           renderTo: "formpanel",
           items: [{
               xtype: "textfield",
               name: "name__like",
               value: "mont"
           }, {
               xtype: "textfield",
               name: "elevation__ge",
               value: "2000"
           }]
       });
```

I create a filter like this "`cond1 AND cond2 AND` .." in wfs. I want to use `AND` and `OR` definition on both of them. What should I do?

Comment: @rLyLmZ I know, it's tempting, but code formatting should be used for code only.